# NuGet install-package from solution

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to *add* a package to a project when this package is already added to another project? I would like to avoid depending on the net because sometimes we are require to work in a non connected scenario. 
I know I can simple add a reference and browse, but I suspect I will loose the ability to update automatically the reference in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to be able to work with NuGet in a non-connected state, is to supply an alternative package source, either locally on your own computer, or on a machine on your internal network. You can add new package sources in Visual Studio through *Tools > Options > Package Manager > Package Sources*.

We do this ourselves for two reasons:

- With a local package source you can work without an internet connection.
- With a local package source *and* the official NuGet package source disabled, we have better control of which packages are available. This way will we for instance avoid undesired updates in our development group until we've approved them.

Comment: can the package subdir in the solution used as a package source?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't think so. The folder you specify as a package source must (I think) contain .nupkg files directly inside the folder. If you however look inside the `packages` folder in your solution, you'll see a sub folder for each package, which again contains lots of files for that package (among others, the .nupgk and .nuspec file).